# String which is not in datetime format to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime, type-conversion

I have a string which is not in a datetime format eg:`20160503`. How can i change it to Datetime. I tried using Substring. It is working.Is there any more efficient way? Below is what I have right now.

```
string a = "20160503";
int b = Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(0, 4));
int c = Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(4, 2));
int d = Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(6, 2));
string date = b + "/" + c + "/" + d;
DateTime result = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParse(date, out result);
```

Comment: Given that todays date is May 3rd 2016, I'd say that you should use the format `YYYYMMdd` and use `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Answer (score 6):

Since you know the *exact* *format* of your datetime, you could try to use the `ParseExact` DateTime's method.

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(a,"yyyyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For further info, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `YYYY` should be `yyyy`. This code now results in the exception `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.

Comment: Getting error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: What if it is not a valid string? say 20161312

Comment: if it's not valid then it's not valid and the method will throw. you can either somehow filter out invalid strings or wrap the parsing in a try/catch.

Comment: To make sure it is a valid string,use [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try somthing like this:

Define your own parse format string to use.

```
string formatString = "yyyyMMdd";
string sample = "20160503";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sample,formatString,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your replies. Finaly I ended up using `DateTime.TryParseExact`

```
string dateString = "20150503";
DateTime dateValue = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue);
```